# python fetchmany not working with oracle cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm working with python and oracle using the cx_Oracle module. I'm having issues getting **fetchmany** to work correctly. The table in the query, i2test, has over 20,000 rows, however the **while loop** hangs when it gets to about 1,800 rows. If I remove the **order by** clause... the loop hangs at about 12,000. Any advice?

```
cursor_metadata = cx_Oracle.Cursor(i_connection)


query_select = """SELECT name, code, cname, TO_CHAR(updatedate), TO_CHAR(downloaddate), TO_CHAR(importdate)
                  FROM imetadata.i2test
                  WHERE code like '%DIN%' AND
                        cd = 'N'
                  ORDER BY code"""


cursor_metadata.execute(query_select)

count = 0
results = cursor_metadata.fetchmany(100)
while results:
    print count
    count += 1
    results = cursor_metadata.fetchmany(100)
```

I realize this is probably something simple... thanks in advance.

*It only seems to hang if when I'm trying to fetch very large row sizes or big columns like varchar(2000). Other Python modules like pymssql don't seem to have this issue.

Column definitions:

`CREATE TABLE IMETADATA.I2TEST 
    (NAME            VARCHAR2(700 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
     CNAME           VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
     CODE            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
     UPDATEDATE      DATE NOT NULL,
     DOWNLOADDATE    DATE,
     IMPORTDATE      DATE)`

Comment: Does it work when you do `cursor_metadata.fetchall()`?

Comment: @Gerrat It does not work... it'll still hang. After some tinkering, I noticed that it only hangs when I include big columns like varchar(2000) or when the rows are too big.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  I've never seen cx_Oracle *hang* in this type of situation.  Usually it will produce some sort of error.  Are you ignoring the errors (maybe via a try/except clause somewhere)?

Comment: @Gerrat I don't have the code wrapped in a try/except. I have no idea what is happening or how to diagnose it, I have to kill the process manually.

Comment: Is the machine you are running on running out of memory (or swapping to disk)?

Comment: I don't think so... other modules like pymssql seem to work on the same database schema without any issue.

Comment: Can you post the column definitions for this table?

Comment: @Gerrat I appended the column definitions to the main post.